# wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to create a new account object for my spec. Below is code, but it fails.

```
@acc = FactoryGirl.create(:account, name: "Test", description: "Something about Test");
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com", password: nil, code: nil);

create_account = Account.create(@acc,@user)
```

**Error**

```
Failure/Error: create_account = Account.create(@acc,@user)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

Below is my actual account creation in controller.

```
@account = Account.create( account: { name: "#{params[:account][:name]}", description: "#{params[:description]}" }, user: { email: current_user.email })
```

Why am i getting wrong number of `arguments` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote it wrongly. Write as below :-

```
create_account = Account.create(account: @acc, user: @user)
```

In Rails [#create](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class)

> The *attributes* parameter can be either be a `Hash` or an `Array` of *Hashes*. These *Hashes* describe the *attributes* on the objects that are to be created.

Comment: I am using rspec-rails 3.0.... how would i use expect in this case.

Comment: Take ideas from here - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#equivalence and https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs

Answer (score 3):

You should have:

```
Account.create(account: @acc, user: @user)
```

in your spec. You're getting an error because you pass two parameters into `create` method, while you should pass at most one param (like in my example - you pass `{account: @acc, user: @user}` hash.

Comment: Thanks its working, but when i try to create_account.name.should = "Test" its failing saying undefined method should.

Comment: @UnderTaker Use `#expect`.. May be you are in current version of Rspec.